# How to apply multiple tags to a window in dvtm?

Tags: terminal

It seems that it is intended for windows in dvtm to be able to have multiple tags applied.  That is, `Mod-t-2`, `Mod-t-3` ought to leave the currently focused window with both tags 2 and 3.  However, for that to work, it seems that we need to apply a patch like https://github.com/wrp/dvtm/commit/3a6f3687399f6e3c853b7604d482dc12ff778ab3  Since I'm fairly new to dvtm, I'm going to assume that the patch is not necessary, but that I have a fundamental misunderstanding of how tags are supposed to work.  The question is:

how does one apply multiple tags to a window?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Mod-t` is intended to set the tagset to be exclusively the set tag, but in the default keybindings, `Mod-T` can be used to toggle items in the set.  This seems like a bug...